# Why should we use the search bar at the top right? Ask a question!

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions, search

Sometimes when I search using the text box on the top right, I get very few or no results. How disappointing!

But if I click "Ask A Question", I get a box called "Questions that may already have your answer" and it always shows quite a lot of questions.

I am guessing the algorithm is different. So why don't use the "Questions that may already have your answer" algorithm (let this be algorithm A) to replace the current search bar algorithm (let this be Algorithm B)?

Here are my thoughts:

If A replaces B, then there will probably be the same amount of results each time. So in normal situations, we use A, if no or few results are found, use algorithm B.

Alternatively, we can mix A and B together!

Comment: Option C: Google. SO's search algorithm is... mediocre.

Comment: When you use the search, is it perhaps already filtering on a particular tag? I've fallen into that trap a few times myself. But generally I use google to search for stuff on stackoverflow.